# What does (node/enable-util-print!) do?

Tags: javascript, node.js, clojure, clojurescript

In a ClojureScript project targetting nodejs, what exactly is going on behind the scenes with the following common statement?

```
(node/enable-util-print!)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you [check the source out](https://crossclj.info/fun/cljs.nodejs.cljs/enable-util-print!.html) you'll see it's defining a few dynamic variables, which are then used for printing to console, e.g. via [`string-print`](https://crossclj.info/ns/org.clojure/clojurescript/1.7.228/cljs.core.cljs.html#_string-print) and other functions.

Without it, the [base definition of `*print-fn*`](https://crossclj.info/ns/org.clojure/clojurescript/1.7.228/cljs.core.cljs.html#_*print-fn*) throws an error as you are required to set something appropriate for the environment you're running in.